# Why does Font-Awesome not work with Quasar/Vite?

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, quasar-framework

I have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/font-awesome@latest/css/font-awesome.min.css">
...
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
```

This works but I would like to use Quasar (using Vite) so I add the following to my main.js file...

```
import iconSet from 'quasar/icon-set/fontawesome-v6';
import '@quasar/extras/fontawesome-v6/fontawesome-v6.css';
import "quasar/src/css/index.sass";
app.use(Quasar, {
    iconSet: iconSet,
    plugins: {}, // import Quasar plugins and add here
});
...
<q-btn dense flat icon="close" />
```

But the icon does not show up instead I see close. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using Quasar Cli Vite or Vite plugin?

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need to import it in your app, just configure `quasar.config.js`:
https://quasar.dev/options/installing-icon-libraries#introduction

```js
extras: [
  // 'ionicons-v4',
  // 'mdi-v5',
  'fontawesome-v6',
  // 'eva-icons',
  // 'themify',
  // 'line-awesome',
  // 'roboto-font-latin-ext', // this or either 'roboto-font', NEVER both!

  // 'roboto-font', // optional, you are not bound to it
  // 'material-icons', // optional, you are not bound to it
  // 'material-icons-outlined',
  // 'material-symbols-outlined'
],
```

Then use it wherever you want

```html
<q-icon name="fa-solid fa-ambulance" />
```

Also, please note how to correctly use the font name as per library choosen
https://quasar.dev/vue-components/icon#webfont-usage

When using font-awesome, the icon name should be

`fa-[solid,regular,brands] fa-`